# Parachain doesn't producing block

Tags: parachain, block, zombienet

I was building a Parachain using Zombienet. However, I was having trouble generating blocks on Parachain.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Relaychain and Parachain using v0.9.37 version

zombienet config

```
[relaychain]
default_command = "../polkadot/target/release/polkadot"
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 1001
chain = "local"
cumulus_based = true

    # run alice as parachain collator
    [[parachains.collators]]
    name = "alice"
    validator = true
    command = "./target/release/parachain-template-node"
    args = ["-lparachain=debug"]
```

I attach log below

```
2023-03-16 07:48:00.038  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.038  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #49 (0x42b0…c38b)    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.040  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b at=0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853
2023-03-16 07:48:00.041 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=49 block_hash=0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b num_candidates=0
2023-03-16 07:48:00.041 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b, 49)]
2023-03-16 07:48:00.041  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (1 ms) [hash: 0x04f4592592a48185e0ea71edd98706779bef1ae5f45f85f225f0af53c71cb27c; parent_hash: 0x6a44…5853; extrinsics (2): [0x9f6a…baa2, 0x84bf…8737]]    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0xa25ce1d8560373d3bac7747a4d737745a392c8f4223eb569465193da277c44c2, previously 0x04f4592592a48185e0ea71edd98706779bef1ae5f45f85f225f0af53c71cb27c.    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Detected leaves overflow at height 1, removing 1 obsolete blocks    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Removing block (@1) 0xda99d95ee356aea604cdf37855187309681d750d6e46639db49149d14713430f    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #1 (0xa25c…44c2)    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.1787109375kb, extrinsics: 2.5634765625kb, storage_proof: 2.541015625kb }
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 4.5361328125kb
2023-03-16 07:48:00.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Produced proof-of-validity candidate. block_hash=0xa25ce1d8560373d3bac7747a4d737745a392c8f4223eb569465193da277c44c2
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0xf511dd8ef44acff2bfee58402a6ac906647697e16bc36f8b86161197b60b63b8 pov_hash=0x4d08becdfdbae1dc5d0f525b223785bc4614abc65808e2f46a84ef61c7a15467 relay_parent=0x97169d4c94c9a6c652b37312e3c0ff5aeabdbfb9f6e026fad219242e2dd786e2 para_id=1337 traceID=325753621752425749890681166552416045318
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=4
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=1337 relay_parent=0x9716…86e2 candidate_hash=0xf511dd8ef44acff2bfee58402a6ac906647697e16bc36f8b86161197b60b63b8 pov_hash=0x4d08becdfdbae1dc5d0f525b223785bc4614abc65808e2f46a84ef61c7a15467 core=CoreIndex(0) current_validators=[Public(d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d (5GrwvaEF...))] traceID=325753621752425749890681166552416045318
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2023-03-16 07:48:00.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=0
2023-03-16 07:48:00.045  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (0 ms) [hash: 0xfb1afa4c5eda34bf76380e575e53b2aff568686e0badb9fe301406852b8c121d; parent_hash: 0x6a44…5853; extrinsics (2): [0xc39d…d23a, 0xa2fa…0ddd]]    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.047  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0xc3ad69af821fa178b368c9ffb327301a91a8c5ac13f88bb7e3a2abda338e0241, previously 0xfb1afa4c5eda34bf76380e575e53b2aff568686e0badb9fe301406852b8c121d.    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.047 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Detected leaves overflow at height 1, removing 1 obsolete blocks    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.047 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Removing block (@1) 0x6faa1282cd1a89c082ea48824f312374b531ebd60a07b45527369e47c3b08ac7    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.048  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #1 (0xc3ad…0241)    
2023-03-16 07:48:00.048  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.1787109375kb, extrinsics: 2.5634765625kb, storage_proof: 2.541015625kb }
2023-03-16 07:48:00.048  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 4.5361328125kb
2023-03-16 07:48:00.048  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Produced proof-of-validity candidate. block_hash=0xc3ad69af821fa178b368c9ffb327301a91a8c5ac13f88bb7e3a2abda338e0241
2023-03-16 07:48:00.049 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0x8d0b0abfdc3356f0349ec3c2caa16f183208b84ab0e35f6c8485a58c5edf0772 pov_hash=0x0786675eafd45289475ec7ac9e0cb4478f5087023a53acb4bb86477c57d8cfd9 relay_parent=0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b para_id=1337 traceID=187478480695940865856567399663383179032
2023-03-16 07:48:00.049 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=4
2023-03-16 07:48:00.049 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=1337 relay_parent=0x42b0…c38b candidate_hash=0x8d0b0abfdc3356f0349ec3c2caa16f183208b84ab0e35f6c8485a58c5edf0772 pov_hash=0x0786675eafd45289475ec7ac9e0cb4478f5087023a53acb4bb86477c57d8cfd9 core=CoreIndex(0) current_validators=[Public(d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d (5GrwvaEF...))] traceID=187478480695940865856567399663383179032
2023-03-16 07:48:00.049 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2023-03-16
 07:48:00.049 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=0
2023-03-16 07:48:02.779 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::network-bridge-rx: [Relaychain] action="PeerConnected" peer_set=Collation version=1 peer=PeerId("12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm") role=Authority
2023-03-16 07:48:02.781 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b peer_id=12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm
2023-03-16 07:48:02.781 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0x97169d4c94c9a6c652b37312e3c0ff5aeabdbfb9f6e026fad219242e2dd786e2 peer_id=12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm
2023-03-16 07:48:02.781 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0xf65066cb2296547f304de69132211de95f6dc04ed809ad6159eef47c9b062d0f peer_id=12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm
2023-03-16 07:48:02.984 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1678830482 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-03-16 07:48:02.984  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #49 (0x9716…86e2), finalized #45 (0x2c6e…45f6), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 3.9kiB/s    
2023-03-16 07:48:03.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6a44…5853), finalized #0 (0x6a44…5853), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s    
2023-03-16 07:48:04.855 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xf65066cb2296547f304de69132211de95f6dc04ed809ad6159eef47c9b062d0f
2023-03-16 07:48:04.855 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Collation was requested. candidate_hash=0xd82c59df80bf9de60cc9d662dd2be5f2324dabee32a738a2563c7cb7a45395a5 pov_hash=0x574f2034b66d8ffccc36df3d2477703c5d56039622870f0044874135f6c85bf1 traceID=287343530993498058386381695300221527538
2023-03-16 07:48:04.855 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x6048d256ee5379df72a11d0b5f154353386934132628ce8af929a0d8f1fdde67 block_number=47
2023-03-16 07:48:04.857 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::network-bridge-rx: [Relaychain] action="PeerDisconnected" peer_set=Collation peer=PeerId("12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm")
2023-03-16 07:48:06.039  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #50 (0xb576…1f64)    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.040 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x97169d4c94c9a6c652b37312e3c0ff5aeabdbfb9f6e026fad219242e2dd786e2
2023-03-16 07:48:06.040 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Collation was requested. candidate_hash=0xf511dd8ef44acff2bfee58402a6ac906647697e16bc36f8b86161197b60b63b8 pov_hash=0x4d08becdfdbae1dc5d0f525b223785bc4614abc65808e2f46a84ef61c7a15467 traceID=325753621752425749890681166552416045318
2023-03-16 07:48:06.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=50 block_hash=0xb5764856a4a518c5522a528c8646cb72ef9a4a68244bcdf390b8b7eda81d1f64 num_candidates=0
2023-03-16 07:48:06.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xb5764856a4a518c5522a528c8646cb72ef9a4a68244bcdf390b8b7eda81d1f64, 50)]
2023-03-16 07:48:06.055  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0xb5764856a4a518c5522a528c8646cb72ef9a4a68244bcdf390b8b7eda81d1f64 at=0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853
2023-03-16 07:48:06.057  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.061  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (0 ms) [hash: 0x643971918fd25b32b209b479d1ddbcd7b68d8ebcf9d9cc1a34c56eeef4871350; parent_hash: 0x6a44…5853; extrinsics (2): [0xe4a7…bfe9, 0x2577…85ed]]    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.065  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0x3225c4901671b2d7c577f510f9983ddc27d684451fd200350c00d32af7837469, previously 0x643971918fd25b32b209b479d1ddbcd7b68d8ebcf9d9cc1a34c56eeef4871350.    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.065 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Detected leaves overflow at height 1, removing 1 obsolete blocks    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.065 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Removing block (@1) 0x9299e349ccef5347477d1a4446c6bc6e794f205fc0d3c1f5db5965d5b69c6e15    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.065  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #1 (0x3225…7469)    
2023-03-16 07:48:06.065  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.1787109375kb, extrinsics: 2.5634765625kb, storage_proof: 2.541015625kb }
2023-03-16 07:48:06.066  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 4.5361328125kb
2023-03-16 07:48:06.066  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Produced proof-of-validity candidate. block_hash=0x3225c4901671b2d7c577f510f9983ddc27d684451fd200350c00d32af7837469
2023-03-16 07:48:06.066 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0x7c928ebfc4dd5b3f59d17e0c6a6a723e018f4e27caa1bc100f871f2b236e5606 pov_hash=0x342f1fcbb03c2ed4ab1760e37e9115351d8e345c893a45afcc7f530894015a0e relay_parent=0xb5764856a4a518c5522a528c8646cb72ef9a4a68244bcdf390b8b7eda81d1f64 para_id=1337 traceID=165585242114345077270611585845787521598
2023-03-16 07:48:06.067 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=4
2023-03-16 07:48:06.067 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=1337 relay_parent=0xb576…1f64 candidate_hash=0x7c928ebfc4dd5b3f59d17e0c6a6a723e018f4e27caa1bc100f871f2b236e5606 pov_hash=0x342f1fcbb03c2ed4ab1760e37e9115351d8e345c893a45afcc7f530894015a0e core=CoreIndex(0) current_validators=[Public(d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d (5GrwvaEF...))] traceID=165585242114345077270611585845787521598
2023-03-16 07:48:06.067 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2023-03-16 07:48:06.067 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=0
2023-03-16 07:48:07.989 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1678830487 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-03-16 07:48:07.989  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #50 (0xb576…1f64), finalized #47 (0x6048…de67), ⬇ 0.9kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2023-03-16 07:48:08.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6a44…5853), finalized #0 (0x6a44…5853), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.042  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  New epoch 5 launching at block 0x80b9…d37a (block slot 279820082 >= start slot 279820082).    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.042  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  Next epoch starts at slot 279820092    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.044  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #51 (0x80b9…d37a)    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.044 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xb5764856a4a518c5522a528c8646cb72ef9a4a68244bcdf390b8b7eda81d1f64
2023-03-16 07:48:12.044  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Collation wasn't advertised to any validator. candidate_hash=0x7c928ebfc4dd5b3f59d17e0c6a6a723e018f4e27caa1bc100f871f2b236e5606 pov_hash=0x342f1fcbb03c2ed4ab1760e37e9115351d8e345c893a45afcc7f530894015a0e traceID=165585242114345077270611585845787521598
2023-03-16 07:48:12.054 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] New session detected session_index=5
2023-03-16 07:48:12.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Determined past/present/future authorities authority_count=2
2023-03-16 07:48:12.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Issuing a connection request num=0
2023-03-16 07:48:12.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] error=NotAValidator
2023-03-16 07:48:12.055 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Validation num_peers=0 removed=0
2023-03-16 07:48:12.056  INFO tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Advanced session window for approvals update=Advanced { prev_window_start: 0, prev_window_end: 4, new_window_start: 0, new_window_end: 5 }
2023-03-16 07:48:12.056  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x80b9cbd9af3186233549151b5081931b8bfbc09d45515c2ca878beecd65ad37a at=0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853
2023-03-16 07:48:12.057  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x6a449488cecc046777312294b9b46a2a91c15dde79612b2c7f93ca0574b55853    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.057 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=51 block_hash=0x80b9cbd9af3186233549151b5081931b8bfbc09d45515c2ca878beecd65ad37a num_candidates=0
2023-03-16 07:48:12.057 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x80b9cbd9af3186233549151b5081931b8bfbc09d45515c2ca878beecd65ad37a, 51)]
2023-03-16 07:48:12.059  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (0 ms) [hash: 0xa30aa31f4521ce6e280715b14035285b14e1519ab5953a4f00da0202290929a2; parent_hash: 0x6a44…5853; extrinsics (2): [0x6893…80bf, 0x4739…cf8e]]    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0x96245bd88f2c9fdc4ecc384e25c9f9352bfb05247a0b92aa5f38e644c7c20f05, previously 0xa30aa31f4521ce6e280715b14035285b14e1519ab5953a4f00da0202290929a2.    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Detected leaves overflow at height 1, removing 1 obsolete blocks    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain: [Parachain] Removing block (@1) 0xee767444582d6da85df4f3a9118c998f298d0497fb044c9bad00761736f8c5c6    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.1787109375kb, extrinsics: 2.5634765625kb, storage_proof: 2.541015625kb }
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 4.537109375kb
2023-03-16 07:48:12.061  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #1 (0x9624…0f05)    
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Produced proof-of-validity candidate. block_hash=0x96245bd88f2c9fdc4ecc384e25c9f9352bfb05247a0b92aa5f38e644c7c20f05
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0x65a64007b79c04e658a0cb4c19efc74178678e3742f88af4f54bb2d16f084589 pov_hash=0x67ce387919b018691493b26b457935d7ba5e7d7902a697e0eb4d5d93ae5542fc relay_parent=0x80b9cbd9af3186233549151b5081931b8bfbc09d45515c2ca878beecd65ad37a para_id=1337 traceID=135115247538429428220147497216846579521
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=5
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=1337 relay_parent=0x80b9…d37a candidate_hash=0x65a64007b79c04e658a0cb4c19efc74178678e3742f88af4f54bb2d16f084589 pov_hash=0x67ce387919b018691493b26b457935d7ba5e7d7902a697e0eb4d5d93ae5542fc core=CoreIndex(0) current_validators=[Public(8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48 (5FHneW46...))] traceID=135115247538429428220147497216846579521
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators request peer_set=Collation requested=1 failed_to_resolve=0
2023-03-16 07:48:12.062 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Collation num_peers=1 removed=1
2023-03-16 07:48:12.063 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::network-bridge-rx: [Relaychain] action="PeerConnected" peer_set=Collation version=1 peer=PeerId("12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby") role=Authority
2023-03-16 07:48:12.064 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0x42b02bdd83099dfa31186f96660e53a22baa0f28cdd2e4efa89abc86efc2c38b peer_id=12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby
2023-03-16 07:48:12.064 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Advertising collation. relay_parent=0x80b9cbd9af3186233549151b5081931b8bfbc09d45515c2ca878beecd65ad37a peer_id=12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby
2023-03-16 07:48:12.994 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1678830492 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-03-16 07:48:12.994  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #51 (0x80b9…d37a), finalized #47 (0x6048…de67), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 2.4kiB/s    
2023-03-16 07:48:13.047  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6a44…5853), finalized #0 (0x6a44…5853), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-03-16 07:48:17.994 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1678830497 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-03-16 07:48:17.995  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #51 (0x80b9…d37a), finalized #47 (0x6048…de67), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2023-03-16 07:48:18.051  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6a44…5853), finalized #0 (0x6a44…5853), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s
```

EDIT:

In relaychain it comes error with below

```
2023-03-16 16:00:02 Failed to validate candidate para_id=Id(1000) error=InvalidCandidate(WorkerReportedError("execute: execute error: RuntimeConstruction(Other(\"failed to instantiate a new WASM module instance: Insufficient resources: memory minimum size of 2086 pages exceeds memory limits\"))"))
```

Comment: Tidy up your device in terms of memory and try it again, I think you don't have enough memory space.

Comment: Hi, yes looks like a resource issues. can you try in another device with more memory? Thanks!

Comment: I am using M1 MBP with 32GB memory. Is not enough?

Comment: Your hardware should be fine. I think the problem resides specifically for the release 0.9.37 and mac. I face the same issue and trying with different rust toolset i cannot get rid of the issue in the validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error you're encountering is related to the WASM module instance running out of memory resources. To resolve this issue, you can try increasing the memory limits for the WASM module instance in your Polkadot Substrate runtime.

Here are the steps to fix the error:

1. Locate your Substrate runtime's runtime/src/lib.rs file.
2. Find the construct_runtime! macro and look for the WasmExecutionMethod parameter in your system pallet configuration. If it's not present, you'll need to add it.
3. Set the WasmExecutionMethod to Interpreted or Compiled, depending on your preference. The Interpreted method is more resource-friendly but slower, while the Compiled method is faster but requires more resources. In your case, it might be a good idea to start with the Interpreted method.

Example:

```rust
parameter_types! { 
pub const WasmExecutionMethod: sc_executor::WasmExecutionMethod = sc_executor::WasmExecutionMethod::Interpreted;
}
```

4. Make sure to import the required dependencies:

```rust
use sc_executor;
```

5. In the construct_runtime! macro, add the WasmExecutionMethod
   configuration to the System pallet:

```rust
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        // Other pallets...

        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);
```

6. Add the WasmExecutionMethod parameter to the System configuration:

```rust
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    // Other configuration values...

    type WasmExecutionMethod = WasmExecutionMethod;
}
```

7. Save your changes and rebuild your Substrate node.
8. Start your node again and check if the error persists.

These steps should help you resolve the "Insufficient resources" error in your Polkadot Substrate runtime. If you still encounter issues, you may need to further adjust your runtime's memory configuration or optimize your runtime logic to consume less memory.

Comment: I would recommend you to review this answer since it has some inconsistencies like the type WasmExecutionMethod in the frame_system::Config. That type does not exist for the frame_system pallet.

Comment: Right, this error seems to have been an issue about WASM blob size. Sorry for the confusion.